# only the first id of the product is being added to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

first time am using this, so i hope to have as much help as needed

hi guys, i have 2 tables - tblproduct and tblretprod.
i insert my product details to tbl product with prod_id being auto increment
other fields are prod_name, prod_brand, prod_desc, prod_photo, cat, subcat

i hv another table tblretprod with fields id, user_id, prod_id, prod_price

i can add my products successfully

i am displaying all the products i added in a table i echo along with a textfield to enter the product price and an add button

on clicking the add button, user_id for the session, prod_id and prod_price should be inserted in the tblretprod

user_id and prod_price are being inserted correctly, but the prod_id which is unique to each product is not being added. only the first prod_id i.e 1 is being added everywhere

here are my codes to add the product when i click on add

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('db_connect.php');
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $prod_price = $_POST['prod_price'];
    $url='retprod.php';
    $sql=mysql_query("select user_id from tbllogin where username = '$username'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $sql1 = mysql_query("select * from tblproduct");
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
    $sql2 = mysql_query("insert into tblretprod (user_id, prod_id, prod_price) values   ('$row[user_id]', '$row1[prod_id]', '$prod_price')");
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
    echo "<script>alert('This product has been added successfully.')</script>";
?>
```

i tried this:-

```
$prod_id = $_POST['prod_id'];
// or
$prod_id = $_GET['prod_id'];
$sql1 = mysql_query("select * from tblproduct where prod_id='$prod_id'");
```

this didn't work either

what i want to do in short is that when the user fills in the text field with the product price and clicks on the add button, the relative user_id, prod_id of the product and the price entered are stored in tblretprod. user_id and price are being saved but not the relative prod_id

---

i am trying the below code and i know it can work but i don't know where there is an error in the code. Can anyone help me out please? I know am using a deprecated mysql codes but my project is nearly complete.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
 extract($row); 

 echo "<tr>";
 echo '<td style="text-align:center;"><img height="100" width="100"   src="Images/Products/'.$row['prod_photo'].'" alt="'.$row['prod
  _name'].'" /></td>';
  echo "<td style="text-align: center;">".$row['prod_name']."</td>";
  echo "<td style="text-align: center;">".$row['prod_brand']."</td>";
  echo "<td>"."<form name=\"price\" method=\"post\" action=\"ret_addprod.php\">".
    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"prod_id\" value=\"'.$row['prod_id'].'\" />.
    "<center><input type=\"text\" name=\"prod_price\" />.
    "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add\" /></form>"."</td>";


}
```

Comment: insert your execution of $sql2 inside of a loop that iterates over each entry of $row1;

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please pay a little more attention to the english grammar when you ask a question (ie: punctuation, capital letters, no "i"). It looks much more serious if you write correctly.

Comment: There is no question at all, its just a description how the posted code-example works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Ok thank you for the advice. I will take care in writing my queries well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your not putting a filter on your `tblproduct` query. So it will always be the first row of that table that will be inserted.

change `$sql1 = mysql_query("select * from tblproduct");`

to something like `$sql1 = mysql_query("select * from tblproduct WHERE id = '$filter'");`

Comment: I used the code provided. The $filter should be defined i think. How do i do that please? When i tried the code, only the price is inserted along with the user_id but not the prod_id.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `while` loop to iterate all values.

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {
    $sql2 = mysql_query("insert into tblretprod (user_id, prod_id, prod_price) 
    values   ('$row[user_id]', '$row1[prod_id]', '$prod_price')");
}
```

In your current code you have used `$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)` which will give  you only 1st value not all values.

**Note:** Switch to `MySQLi` OR `PDO` because `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Comment: he only needs 1 row to be inserted, i think the issue is with lack of filter in the tblproduct query

Comment: @DevZer0 It can be, but OP has doesn't provide enough info.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar: If that's the case, close-vote the question so that it can get on hold and then wait until OP has improved the question.

Comment: well the question is how do i get the prod_id of each product to the tblretprod when i add the price of each product? i tried the code above but the price i am inserting is not being taken in...if the last prod_id is 10, all prices are set to 10...quite weird